# Long int out of range

Tags: c

I have the following problem. When executed this code the value of variable lonpk exceeds the limit of a long int value and the program prints a incorrect value.The problem consists in to calculate the numbers cubed that add up 100

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main(void){

for (long i = -2000; i <= 2000; i++) {
        long pi = i * i * i;
        if ((i > 0) && (pi > 100)) {
            break;
        }
        for (long j = i; j <= 2000; j++) {
            long pj = (pi + (j * j * j));
            if ((j > 0) && (pj > 100)) {
                break;
            }
            for (long k = j; k <= 2000; k++) {
                long pk = pj + (k * k * k);
                if ((k > 0) && (pk > 100)) {
                    break;
                }

                if (pk == 100.0) {
                    printf("%ld",pk);
                    printf("primer numero=%ld segundo numero=%ld  tercer numero=%ld\n",i,j,k);

                }
            }
        }
   }
    getch();
}
```

incorrect result

```
    primer numero=-1971 segundo numero=-986  tercer numero=295    
correct result    
    primer numero=-1797 segundo numero=1870  tercer numero=-903
```

Comment: Nothing c++ specific, removed the tag.

Comment: `void main()` Nooooooo. Dont do this to us. Change this to `int main()`

Comment: @rubystudent I would `#include <stdint.h>` and then use `int64_t` instead of `long`.

Comment: How do I declare a variable in int64_t?

Comment: Replace the word `long` with `int64_t`. Note that `int64_t` is a typedef for a 64-bit integer, and the typedef is in stdint.h. So you need to `#include <stdint.h>` before you can use it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: If the program is being compiled as C++, the question should be tagged C++. You know this bro

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ can we not start that again? C and C++ are different languages. If someone uses a C++ compiler and writes a C++ program that uses code which happens to form a valid C program also, it is still a C++ program. This has been decided on meta plenty of times.

Comment: @JackWilliams: Better: `int main(void)` (`int main()` is better if you're using C++).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform math with `long long` as that has the needed range of `pow(2000,3)`.

Notice the the lines of code below.  The first can overflow, assuming `ULNG_MAX == 2**32 - 1`, whereas the second, by multiplying initial by `1LL` forces `long long` math to be used -=- which is at least 64-bit.

```
 long i;
 i * i * i
 1LL * i * i * i
```

Code:

```
for (long i = -2000; i <= 2000; i++) {
        long long pi = 1LL * i * (i * i);
        if ((i > 0) && (pi > 100)) {
            break;
        }
        for (long j = i; j <= 2000; j++) {
            long long pj = (pi + (1LL*j * (j * j)));
            if ((j > 0) && (pj > 100)) {
                break;
            }
            for (long k = j; k <= 2000; k++) {
                long long pk = pj + (1LL * k * (k * k));
                if ((k > 0) && (pk > 100)) {
                    break;
                }

                if (pk == 100) {
                    printf("%lld",pk);
                    printf("primer numero=%ld segundo numero=%ld  tercer numero=%ld\n"
                        ,i,j,k);

                }
            }
        }
   }
    getch();
}
```

---

OP does not have access to `long long`, then use `double` which *likely* has enough range/precision for this task.

```
int main(void) {
  for (long i = -2000; i <= 2000; i++) {
    double pi = 1.0 * i * (i * i);
    if ((i > 0) && (pi > 100)) {
      break;
    }
    for (long j = i; j <= 2000; j++) {
      double pj = (pi + (1.0 * j * (j * j)));
      if ((j > 0) && (pj > 100)) {
        break;
      }
      for (long k = j; k <= 2000; k++) {
        double pk = pj + (1.0 * k * (k * k));
        if ((k > 0) && (pk > 100)) {
          break;
        }

        if (pk == 100) {
          printf("%.0f", pk);
          printf("primer numero=%ld segundo numero=%ld  tercer numero=%ld\n", i, j, k);
          fflush(stdout);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  getch();
  return 0;
}

100primer numero=-1797 segundo numero=-903  tercer numero=1870
100primer numero=-161 segundo numero=-139  tercer numero=190
100primer numero=-6 segundo numero=-3  tercer numero=7
```

---

[Edit] major speed up - reduce `for(k)`, maybe 50x faster

```
  // k*k*k + pj = 100;
  // k = pow(100 - pj, 1.0/3)
  long kmin = (long) pow(100 - pj, 1.0/3) - 1;
  if (kmin < j) kmin = j;
  for (long k = kmin; k <= 2000; k++) {
    double pk = pj + (1.0 * k * k * k);
    if ((k > 0) && (pk > 100)) {
      break;
    }
```

Comment: I have a problem with long long  "Too many types in declaration ." I am using borland c++ 4,5

Comment: @rubystudent: C++ didn't add support for `long long` until relatively recently. It's possible your compiler just doesn't support an integer type wider than 32 bits. Can you use a newer compiler? If not, consult your compiler's documentation; it might have something you can use.

Comment: @ruby student  Hmmm,  For now, try running the code in the range -500 to 500.  (At least 2 answers there.)  I will think of some ideas.

Comment: Don't worry. I am going to searching for a modern compiler

Comment: Could use `double`, even BC 4.5 has that and that typically has enough precision/range.

Comment: I used double type. but the search takes longer

Comment: What compiler do you recommend me?

Comment: @ruby student Even with `double`, it is a lot faster now.

Comment: BC and TC are so ancient that it's older than the first C/C++ standard. Do not use it anymore

Comment: major speed up - reduce for(k), maybe 50x faster . Could you write the complete code with major speed up? chux